# Display file size in a directory

Tags: directory

I am hoping to return and print a dictionary of the files and their file size, what I have written is this;

```
file_size = {}

for fn in glob.glob('*'):
    with os.stat(fn) as f:
        file_size[fn] = f.st_size

print (file_size)
```

But I am getting the AtributeError: **enter**

Answer (score 0):

To use **with** statement you need to have the methods `__enter__()` and `__exit__()` in the object methods.

That is not the case for `os.stat()`. Remove the **with** statement and your problem will be fixed:

```
import glob, os

file_size = {}

for fn in glob.glob('*'):
    f = os.stat(fn)
    file_size[fn] = f.st_size

print (file_size)
```